# How can I troubleshoot a failure of a firebase function to deploy?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I have been deploying my functions successfully for months now, but today (TODAY!), I can't.  I get a cryptic error (that is not improved with the --debug flag) that says:

```
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function functionName(region)...
Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause
```

Looking in the logs, I see this error:

```
functionName Function cannot be initialized. Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason.
```

I can run the function with no issue in the emulator.

```
+  functions[region-functionName]: http function initialized (http://127.0.0.1:5001/gfc-project/region/functionName).
```

```
>  initialized
i  functions: Beginning execution of "functionName"
i  functions: Finished "functionName" in 191.6546ms
```

I have

- Deleted node_modules in both the root and in the functions directory and `npm install`ed in both.
- Run `npm install firebase-tools -g` to make sure my cli is up to date.
- Deleted the corresponding folder in the gcf-sources bucket

I'm not sure what the next step is. Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like this is affected all functions in my repo.  :(

Comment: OK, this was due to an unused require at the top of one file but I'm still interested in how I could have found that out without painstakingly going through commits.

Comment: With a linter. You don't state the language you use but Node for example has https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import which provides linter rules to catch errors like that. Short of that you could have debug statements in your code to pinpoint where it was failing. If the very first thing that your function does is execute something like `console.log('started')` and *that* doesn't get invoked then you know it's a problem with the code that runs *before* that.

Comment: Good point, but I'm curious is there's a firebase deployment debugging or inspection capability that would give me a more detailed error that I could have found that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use client-side development tools to ensure your function works the way you expect. There are multiple tools and steps involved in ensuring your code will execute in the Cloud Functions environment before you deploy them.

At a minimum you should be using linting tools like [ESLint](https://eslint.org/). [eslint-recommended](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files#using-eslintrecommended) is a set of rules that you can enable that would have caught this error: [no-unused-vars](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-vars) is enabled by that ruleset.

ESLint has a huge number of plugins that will extend its functionality to catch other edge cases that might crop up as well. You'll want to look into plugins specifically related to imports like [eslint-plugin-import](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import) that will enforce additional rules.

You should also look into using TypeScript as it will add another layer of enforcement for code quality. For example TypeScript has an option called [`noUnusedLocals`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUnusedLocals) that will raise an error when you have defined an import but are not using it. Likewise, typescript-eslint has support for [no-unused-vars](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unused-vars/).

Whether you implement either of those recommendations or not, you should always test your function locally with a framework like [vitest](https://vitest.dev/) or [jest](https://jestjs.io/) or [mocha](https://mochajs.org) to ensure you have coverage for:

1. Unit tests, to ensure your individual functions execute properly
2. Integration tests, to ensure that you collective functions work together properly

And you should be using [functions-framework](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs) locally to ensure that your Cloud Function is able to cold start in the same environment as GCP uses. To use it ensure you have added the functions-framework package:

```bash
npm install @google-cloud/functions-framework
```

Then run the function using the framework, for example as a PubSub-triggered function:

```bash
npm run functions-framework --target=$(basename $(pwd)) --signature-type=event --trigger-topic=demo
```

Or for example as an HTTP triggered function:

```bash
npm run functions-framework --target=$(basename $(pwd)) --signature-type=http
```

These examples assume that your named/exported Cloud Function is the same as the directory name that it's in. You can read more about these configuration options in the [Configure the Functions Framework documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/blob/master/README.md#configure-the-functions-framework)

This last step is important because it proves that the function can be started by the framework locally and lets you more easily troubleshoot issues before they occur in the deployed environment. However, if you do encounter errors during or after deploying there are three primary places you should be looking to troubleshoot the issue:

1. [Cloud Build History](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds) - when you deploy the function it will include a link to the logs for the *deployment* which is where GCP runs a series of pre-deploy checks on your function, prepares its dependencies, runs the deploy, and then finally loads your code. Errors that prevent deployment will be shown here, and errors in your code that prevents it from being loaded by functions-framework after it has been deployed will be shown here. For example, if you have a line in your function that says `import { foo } from 'bar'` but that dependency doesn't exist or that named export doesn't exist then this is when that error would surface.
2. [Cloud Logging](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/query;query=resource.type%20%3D%20%22cloud_function%22%0Aresource.labels.function_name%20%3D%20%22yourFunctionName%22;cursorTimestamp=) - when you invoke your function you can view the logs generated by *your code* (including any code you've imported/required) here and this will indicate any errors with the actual *execution* of the code.
3. [Cloud Error Reporting](https://console.cloud.google.com/errors) - when your function's code throws an error that is not caught it will automatically report the error here. This can be useful to separate the errors from other logging noise.

One last recommendation I would make is to have a staging or development environment where you initially deploy code. With a properly configured CI/CD system you can have your code deploy to a live GCP Cloud Functions environment as a final step before being deployed to a wholly separate project for production; only when the code has been validated as working in staging will it be promoted to production, ensuring that faulty deploys don't cause issues for running services. This is the same concept as running the functions locally with the framework with the added benefit of being proven to run in a true GCP project.